# H2 database export uses too much memory

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, h2

I've got a database containing a table loaded with base 64 images that has proved to be a problem when the database grows too much, and we try to export its data.

To reproduce a limit case condition, I've reduced java heapspace to 96Mb with a 700Mb  database so I can assure that if the export works well, It won't rise any more problems (hope so at least).

Also, according to H2 advanced documentation:

```
Storing and Reading Large Objects
If it is possible that the objects don't fit into memory, then the data type CLOB 
(for textual data) or BLOB (for binary data) should be used. 
For these data types, the objects are not fully read into memory, by using streams. 
To store a BLOB, use PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream. 
To store a CLOB, use PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream. 
To read a BLOB, use ResultSet.getBinaryStream, and to read a CLOB, 
use ResultSet.getCharacterStream. When using the client/server mode, 
large BLOB and CLOB data is stored in a temporary file on the client side.
```

The images should be accessed as a character stream. With this approach, I've analyzed the memory report java created once the JVM got out of memory, and the memory leak is located in a class called org.h2.result.ResultDiskBuffer$ResultDiskTape.

If instead of using the Stream approach I use the getString method of JDBC, I get a memory leak in a class named PageResult.

In case someone is interested with the code:

```
/**
 * Exports the data implemented by us.
 * @param conn
 * @return
 */
private static boolean exportData(Connection conn) {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        // Get the table names.
        List<String> tables = getTableNames(conn);

        // For each table...
        for ( String table : tables ) {

            int batch = 0;
            List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Exporting table " + table);

            // Close previous resources
            if ( st != null ) {
                st.close();
            }

            // Create the prepared statement.
            st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table + " LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");

            // Get the columns of the database using its metadata.
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = st.getMetaData();
            for ( int col = 0 ; col < metaData.getColumnCount() ; col++ ) {
                String columnName = metaData.getColumnLabel(col + 1);
                columns.add(columnName);
            }

            // Do while there is data in the table
            do {
                if ( batch % 100 == 0 ) { // Every 100 points, next line
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.print(".");

                if ( rs != null ) { // Close previous resources
                    rs.close();
                }

                // Clears the batch
                st.clearBatch();

                // Execute query to grab a batch of batch size
                st.setInt(1, BATCH_SIZE);
                st.setInt(2, batch * BATCH_SIZE);
                rs = st.executeQuery();

                // Count will hold the number of rows found in the batch. If 0, no more data in the table, so we can break
                // the do while.
                int count = 0;

                // While data is in the result set...
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    // Increase counter
                    count ++;

                    startXMLElement(table);
                    // Write to xml the columns of it.
                    for ( String name : columns) {
                        Reader characterStream = rs.getCharacterStream(name);
                        if ( characterStream == null ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(characterStream);
                        String res = "";
                        String line = null;
                        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                            res += line;
                        }
                        try {
                            br.close();
                            characterStream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e ) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        addXMLAttribute(name, res);
                    }

                    // Write map to xml
                    endXMLElement(table , columns);
                }

                // No more data in table. Break while.
                if ( count == 0 ) {
                    break;
                }

                // Increase the batch for next iteration if data found.
                batch++;

            } while ( true );

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Done exporting " + table);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        if ( st != null ) {
            try {
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if ( rs != null ) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}



/**
 * @param conn
 * @return the names of the table created in the database.
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private static List<String> getTableNames(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();

    tables.add("IMAGECACHE");

    DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);

    while (rs.next()) {
      String name = rs.getString(3);
      String type = rs.getString(4);
      if ( "TABLE".equals(type) && ! tables.contains(name) ) {
          tables.add(name);
      }
    }
    return tables;
}
```

Comment: As extra info for someone who has stumbled into the same problem with H2 import/export procedures, my experience is that:

Export : The absence of a limit in the select query will make H2 load all the table. Therefore, it can fail if a table is too big  running out of memory.

Import : If you try to do everything inside of a transaction, deleting everything first, inserting then, and rolling back if some error occurs, the whole previous DB will be stored in memory in an UndoLog. Therefore, transactions can become a peril. Nonetheless, I haven't experienced many issues with the insert's.

Comment: Do you keep the whole XML in memory? The point where it throws OutOfMemoryError is not necessarily the point where the memory leak is. What I would do is get a full heap dump and analyze that. For H2, regular queries without limit should not run out of memory, because a temporary file should be created with the result set data. The same for large transactions. But yes, currently, large queries and large transactions are slower than small queries and transactions. The class `org.h2.result.ResultDiskBuffer$ResultDiskTape` is responsible for disk access.

Comment: Actually, the "startXMLElement" and such methods are not implemented yet. The plan is to use an streaming xml library for it. Even though, a first approach would be to "sysout" it.

Comment: @Joseph I see. In this case could use analyze a full heap dump, or (usually easier) use `jmap -histo <pid>` to get a heap histogram, a bit before it runs out of memory?

Comment: Hi, I've actually added the JVM arguments : -Xms64m -Xmx96m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to create a heap dump once the out of memory is reached, and set the heap size to "only" 96Mb. Analyzing the hprof files, I've noticed that the classes that hold up to 70-80% are the org.h2 ones.

Comment: Well... _which_ classes hold most of the memory?

Comment: I've seen two different classes that have provoked at a given point in time issues: PageStore (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.3.154/org/h2/store/PageStore.java) and UndoLog ( http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.3.172/org/h2/engine/UndoLog.java#UndoLog ).

Comment: If a lot of memory is used by the undo log, then you have an open large transaction. I don't see any transaction in the code you provided. Possibly the transaction is open _before_ you do this export? (I know where the source code of H2 is by the way.)

Comment: It was in a previous code that used transactions to rollback if something went wrong. I rewrote the code to avoid transactions. Actually, I think I did a pretty dumbass mistake, I was not closing a given statement. Let me check if the close of the statement makes it work properly...

Comment: Closing the statement will not help, it does not commit or roll back a transaction.

Comment: I'll keep this question in my todo list for a while, as we have done a work-around with the client. Either way I'll try to fix it as soon as possible. If I happen to found some info, I'll post it here.